# Kali Linux 2020.2: "server not found" web address error

Tags: kali-linux, firefox

I recently installed Kali Linux 2020.2 and after messing around with terminal found that while my Ethernet-based connection will allow me to ping Google, it won't connect to any web servers through Firefox or the terminal. At first I thought it was the difference in time between my linux and windows systems but after resolving time issues and turning proxy off in Firefox, as well as using about:config to mess with prefetching and IPv6, I'm still stumped. I've found some other threads that seemed similar to my issue, but all were fixed with the browser proxy or about:config settings. There is no firewall blocking connections but `wget http://ubuntu.com` still returns a failure in name resolution.

Comment: kali is really difficult to set up ... why are you using kali?

Comment: I'm confused: You are saying you can successfully ping Google (I guess you did `ping www.google.com`) which would mean name resolution works but the name resolution for ubuntu.com fails? Can you confirm? Are you getting the same behavior with the Kali Linux live system?

Comment: Could you please share the output of `host -v ubuntu.com`, `host -v google.com` and `curl http://ubuntu.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be DNS issue -

First things first, to confirm this is indeed a DNS issue, kindly ping some public IP address and make sure you get response.

`ping 8.8.8.8`

If works, check your DNS settings, never used Kali Linux though, but I assume the DNS server should be specified in `/etc/resolv.conf` file. Set appropriate DNS server there. I use Google's DNS 8.8.8.8.

If you still get the same error, then check the interface config file and see if specific DNS is set for the interface, if yes, change it to appropriate DNS server IP.

If ping to public ip is not working, check if the interface itself is up first.

`ip addr`